# Mask particles created by javascript using CSS mask

Tags: javascript, css

I made a particle system with javascript. Every time a user hovers over a button, a function is called, and a single particle is created, then I assign that to an invisible div. The particle moves from the bottom of the div to the top. The problem is these particles move in a square shape of the div. But, I need to mask these particle to a polygon shape. Every particle moves out of this polygon becomes invisible. I googled the issue -- No luck finding a suitable example.

Comment: the particle is a single image. the function created an image element, and I append it to the div with the id of center.

Comment: what's the polygon face? can you draw an example?

Comment: it is a simple hexagon inside the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if I understood you properly, but based on my understanding I created the following snippet. Try moving the red square. It should be clipped by a hexagon-ish shape. You can create your masks easily [here](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

The code is based on the CSS's `clip-path` property that allows you to define a path that functions as a mask, clipping the contents of a HTML element. Take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) and [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/) article.

I've made 2 `div`s. One is a container (`#box`) and the second is a child of the container (`#polygon`). `#polygon` fills the whole space of its parent and the `clip-path` property is applied to it. Finally the particle is inside `#polygon`. Both `#polygon` and `#box` have set CSS property `overflow: hidden`.

```js
$('#particle').draggable()
```

```css
#box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: purple;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#polygon {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(51% 21%, 79% 35%, 79% 70%, 53% 87%, 25% 72%, 24% 37%);
    clip-path: polygon(51% 21%, 79% 35%, 79% 70%, 53% 87%, 25% 72%, 24% 37%);
}

#particle {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  background: red;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="box">
  <div id="polygon">
      <div id="particle"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Not exactly what I asked for. but it solved my problem bro. I give it a +10 if I could.

Comment: quick question, can I use a png file for clip-path instead of inserting every single point?